# Second monitor not working, only showing as black

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have connected both monitors to the computer and they were both working fine. I haven't used the computer in a while and when I turned it on both monitors showed the same screen during the start up. After that, the one screen went black and I can't seem to find the options to bring me to the settings to adjust the screen options.

Now the big problem here is, I just moved to Germany and the computer I'm using is in German and I don't understand it all.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Please specfify the OS (and desktop manager, if Linux) that you are using. Video cards, acgtul connection (DVI, HDMI, DisplayPort...) can also be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following: `Press windows key + R`

type: `CMD` press return/enter.

type: `displayswitch /extend` press return/enter (this should give you an extended screen)

or type: `displayswitch /clone` press return/enter (this should give you a copy of your main screen)